# Как узнать об изменении свойств объекта, если он не генерирует никаких событий?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть класс, состоящий из набора свойств вида

```
public SomeType Property1 { get; set; }
```

Я не могу править этот класс, но очень хочу следить за изменениями его свойств. Как мне это сделать в реальном времени?

Comment: _"Я не могу править этот класс"_ - можно в рантайме править таблицу методов класса. Так поступают некоторые фреймвёрки юнит-тестирования. Думаю, можно попытаться использовать их, либо реализовать такое самостоятельно.

Comment: Паттерн [«декоратор»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Декоратор_(шаблон_проектирования)) Вам в помощь.

Comment: @ixSci, а если без обертки над конкретным классом? Я бы хотел универсальное generic решение

Comment: Ну это и есть универсально решение, по работы со старым кодом, который менять нельзя. Делаются обёртки, всё переводится на интерфейсы и т.п. — это нормальная практика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как то так

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(SomeClass))[nameof(theSomeClass.Prop1)].AddValueChanged(theSomeClass, eventHandler);
```

Короче получаем `PropertyDescriptionCollection` для типа `SomeClass`, выбираем его свойство Prop1, и добавляем хандлер на его изменение, указав первым параметром экземпляр нужного класса.

Тут есть лишь одна проблема, я пока не придумал, как один хандлер использовать для всех свойств, потому что EventArgs не имеет параметров для события.

Answer (score 1):

Унаследуйте от него свой класс и либо переопределите свойство, либо если он запечатан, создайте своё свойство

```
class myClass : ParentClass
{
    public SomeType myProperty1 { get{return base.Property1;} set{ base.Property1=value; onmyProperty1Changed(); } }
    public event EventHandler myProperty1Changed;
    public void onmyProperty1Changed()
    {
        if(myProperty1Changed!= null) myProperty1Changed(this,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Слишком сложно. У меня есть экземпляр класса, мне нужно будет конвертировать его в новый тип.... да и сам тип полностью дублировать...